# MySQL timestamp is different from Ruby's Time.now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**In mysql** db for records:

`2011-12-09 07:59:00 UTC`

**In ruby** if I do `Time.now`:

`2011-12-09 03:57:46 -0800`

**How would I do a comparison like the following?** (which isn't working)

```
<% if item.exp_date < Time.now %>
    Expired
<% end %>
```

**PS.** It would be great if there a solution where I **don't have to assume** if the DB has times stored ending in `UTC` or `-0800`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with my use of `NOW()` in queries to mysql.

Adding the following to `/etc/my.cnf` fixed the issue:

```
[mysqld_safe]
timezone = UTC
```

Answer (score 2):

Date/Time comparisons using `>` and `<` should work fine regardless of the timezones.

```
[chris@chipbook:~/coding%] pry
[1] pry(main)> a = Time.now
=> 2011-12-09 23:09:14 +1100
[2] pry(main)> b = Time.now.utc
=> 2011-12-09 12:09:44 UTC
[3] pry(main)> a < b
=> true
[4] pry(main)>
```

If you want to coerce times to use a reference timezone for consistency, call `#utc` on them.

Answer (score 0):

The default Rails Timezone is UTC, and ActiveRecord auto-converts times to this one. You can set it in config/application.rb. For comparing times, you can use `Time.zone.now`, which refers to the Timezone set up in application.rb. You can check what Timezones are available with `$ rake time:zones:all`.